# Controlling order of serialization in C#

Tags: serialization, xmlserializer

I'm using an XmlSerializer to serialize an object and write it to a file.  I've had quite a bit of success with the serializer doing what I want it to do in terms of nesting elements and what is serialized as elements vs attributes.  Unfortunately, I've run into a problem where I need one member of a class to serialize before another.  Elsewhere it's worked for me that whatever is declared first gets serialized first, but in this instance I'm not having so much success with that.  Is there any way to manually control the order in which things are serialized?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
[XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)] 
public int Field1 {...} 

[XmlElementAttribute(Order = 2)] 
public int Field2 {...}
```

Catch: You must specify the `Order` for *all of your members*.

Be careful - deserialization will only work if the properties in the XML document are in the same order. Otherwise it will silently ignore out-of-order properties.

Comment: Perfect.  I guess I either missed that on MSDN or didn't dig enough to find it.  Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related: Is there any way to control the order with XML attributes?  `XmlAttributeAttribute` does not have such a property.

Comment: @Travis: In my experience, there are fewer (if any) problems with getting attributes to serialize in the order they are declared.

Comment: if you don't specify order for all does it add the rest at the end or at the start? Would be nice to allow negative numbers to control that

Comment: to answer my own comment, unfortunately XmlSerializer requires you to add order for all elements and to have such at ancestor classes too. If you can't control ancestor class, can use XmlAttributeOverride as I show here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bvbi0N

Answer (score 3):

[`XmlElementAttribute.Order`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.order.aspx), which controls "the explicit order in which the elements are serialized or deserialized".