# How to use XmlElementAttribute in VB.Net to order the fields for XML serialization

Tags: vb.net, attributes, xmlserializer, c#-to-vb.net

We need to specify a certain sort order for the fields of a class which is serialized to XML. I appreciate that it's not necessarily good practice to rely on sort order when dealing with XML elements but in our case there's a reason to do so.

So ... [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373529/controlling-order-of-serialization-in-c/3373580#3373580) for C# advises using `XmlElementAttribute` and I've translated the C# to VB as:

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)> _
Public Property Foo() As String
etcs
```

But it complains that `Name 'Order 'is not declared`. Have I mistranslated from C# or is there some other issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The named property assignment syntax is incorrect and should be:

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order := 1)>
```

Note the extra `:` after the `=`. This is for named properties that are not part of a constructor.