# How to specify the order of attributes of XMLSerializer in Java script?

Tags: javascript, xmlserializer

In javascript can I specify the order of attributes of XMLSerializer output. This is my code.

```
var serializer = new XMLSerializer ();
var str = serializer.serializeToString (document);
```

When I try to write this 'str' value to Window.document and again serialize it, I get attributes in different orders.

For example: 
In first serialize output 
    `<img style="width: 10%" src="../Koala.jpg" />`

In second serialize output 
    `<img src="../Koala.jpg" style="width: 10%" />`

I want both this outputs to be equal. Since I want to do a string comparison this is an essential requirement. Pls suggest me a way to get this done.. Thank in advance..

Comment: this article will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373529/controlling-order-of-serialization-in-c-sharp

Comment: String comparison for XML code is not a good tool for the job. Use [tag:xpath]. Order of attributes in XML is irrelevant.